# inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB for table join

Tags: oracle, join, clob

Oracle XE 11.  a very simple join query gave me the following error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
```

Tables:

```
Product
----------------------------------
id, name, description, categoryId 


Catetory
------------------
id, name
```

The product description is CLOB.

SQL> desc Product;

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(19)
 NAME                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
 CATEGORYID                                         NUMBER(19)
 DESCRIPTION                                        CLOB
```

SQL> desc Category;

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(19)
 NAME                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.DESCRIPTION, t1.NAME, t0.name FROM Product t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Category t0 ON (t0.ID = t1.categoryId);
```

ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

IF I remove the t0.name from selection, it will work. weird.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.DESCRIPTION, t1.NAME FROM Product t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Category t0 ON (t0.ID = t1.categoryId);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `DISTINCT` keyword cannot be used for `CLOB` datatypes.
The workaround is :

```
SELECT a.*
     , b.clob
 FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT
               ... /* columns list wihtout clob columns */
         FROM  ...
        ) a
 JOIN
       table_with_clobs b
  ON   ...
```

Going to your sample it would be:

```
SELECT Po.ID, Po.DESCRIPTION, Po.NAME, PC.CatName 
  FROM
   ( SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t0.name CatName 
       FROM Product t1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Category t0 
         ON t0.ID = t1.categoryId 
    ) PC
    join Product PO
    on PO.ID = PC.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

If your clob column does not contain more than 4000 characters, you could try this..

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, to_char(t1.DESCRIPTION), t1.NAME FROM Product t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Category t0 ON (t0.ID = t1.categoryId);
```

Comment: To add detail, the DISTINCT and the CLOB cause issues. Trying to de-duplicate CLOBs that potentially run into gigabytes is not supported.

Answer (score -1):

As @dcieslak has already stated, The `DISTINCT` keyword cannot be used for `CLOB` datatypes.

> IF I remove the t0.name from selection, it will work. weird.

I guess there is an unique index on `Product.id` column. When you remove `t0.name` from `SELECT` clause, all selected columns com from the same table. So when one of those columns have unique values (`t1.id` in your case), then all rows will always be unique. And that implies that there is no need for any comparison of `CLOB` columns.

BUT
if there is an unique index on `Product.id`, then you do not need `DISTINCT` keyword at all. For query:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.DESCRIPTION, t1.NAME, t0.name FROM Product t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Category t0 ON (t0.ID = t1.categoryId);
```

you will get exactly one row for each row from `Product` table, which must be distinct due to distinct `t1.ID` values.